# Why is different CSS3 rotate + translate vs rotate + left

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following code:
CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    margin:80px  auto;
    width:300px;
    border:none;
}
.square {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;   
    transform-origin:0% 0%;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;

}
.square:hover{
    transform:rotate(45deg) translateX(200px);  
    transition: transform 5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

**Expected transition:** One square moving to the right as long as its rotating all at a time.

**Actual Result:** Some kind of circular path for the square translation as it rotates.

However I achieved the Expected transition while changing the *:hover* pseudo class to:

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
    left:400px;
    transition: left 5s,transform 5s;
```

So that instead of *translate* ,the movement be made via *left* property

My question is: Why can't I achieve the same result via left property than with TranslateX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on Chrome (Ubuntu) and putting `translate` before `rotate` removed that circular behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/4tMzz/1/

Comment: You're right. Only thing is: I wonder why the order has such a dramatic difference in the result: :)